# How can I read and parse a date and time in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, datetime, date

I have a date and time `2011-02-28 07:00:52` as a string. How can I read it and then parse it as a date and time to compare it to an Android system time and date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String time; // your string representing the time
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date startDate = dateFormatter.parse(time);
```

and

```
new Date()
```

will give you a date representing the current date and time.

Comment: In my case, I had to put hyphens, a space, and colons in the parameter:
... = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

When comparing dates, once you have the date object as shown by kett_chup, use date.getTime() which gives you the milliseconds and you can then easily compare with another date.getTime() to determine if one date came before or after the other.